# Mint with white / yellow spots and eaten leaves- advice on how to treat?

Tags: diagnosis, mint, discoloration

Any help identifying what's going on here and how to help is much appreciated!! This is mint I bought and potted. It's grown quite a bit but I am noticing these white / yellow flecks, brown spots and also leaves that are being eaten. I am assuming insects? Thank you for your help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the leaf give off some smell

Comment: It might be spider mites and other suckling bugs. Here is the [https://gardeningmentor.com/why-are-there-white-spots-on-mint-leaves] (source).